# how to set id of camel processor or other route ingredients

Tags: apache-camel

Camel automatically generates id for processors and other stuff (processor1..processor25). Is there a way to set this name? We need to identify certain processors via jmx to get telemetry data.

The names I want to set are given via properties - they are known on start time. So I need to set them when route is defined or within the processor (name is given via processors constructor, the string is also used for processing).

**Update**

Example: for a route `from("some:where").process(myProcessor).to(no:where)` i need to set the id of myProcessor. I need "ExchangesTotal" and other stuff from certain processors

I need a solution in Java DSL.

Comment: Does setting them up like this help: `<bean id="myProcessor" class="com.acme.MyProcessor"/>`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If using xml then use the id attribute.

```
<to id="foo" uri="seda:foo"/>
```

And if using java code, then use `.id`

```
.to("seda:bar").id("foo");
```

And one special is to set the id of the route, which you must use `.routeId`

```
from("xxx").routeId("id of the route")
   .to("xxx")
```

So your example should be

```
from("some:where").process(myProcessor).id("theIdOfTheProcessorYouWant").to(no:where)
```