# In Apache Camel RouteBuilder configure, what is the difference between .id() and .routeId()

Tags: java, apache-camel, enterprise-integration

What is the difference between

```
configure {
  from (blah blah)
  .id(blah)
  ....
}
```

and

```
configure {
  from (blah blah)
  .routeId(blah)
  .. ..
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the "camel" guy. https://stackoverflow.com/a/28579582/6785908

`.id` is for Identifying individual steps (for Example, processors) in a Route.

On the other hand, `.routeId` is for Identifying the route itself. (You can even bring a route alone down or up by giving the id, without bringing down the application.)

Comment: What is the benefit of ```routeId```?

Answer (score 6):

Both are used for identifying different statements. .`id()` is for identifying statements in a route. `.routeId()` are for identifying routes.

By adding ids you can in your tests use `adviceWith()` to mock or inject or remove parts of your route to perform automated tests without having access to backend systems.